# Why does the CSS styling persist even after being overridden?

Tags: css

[image]

I'm importing an SDK that comes with some default styling but conflicts with my existing application. I've tried overriding the styling by using a more specific selector, which seems to work for the most part except for the **min-width** attribute. In the screenshot, I've declared min-width to 10px to override the SDK's min-width of 1100px. However on the right side, you can see the min-width is still set to 1100px (20 + 1060 + 20). The behavior goes away when I uncheck the checkbox next to min-width: 1100px but it's already crossed out. Why does the styling persist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've overridden the min-width for the body element, but the original selector applied it to both the body and the html elements.

The width of the body is "auto", so it expands to fill the html element.

Comment: That was it! So foolish of me to miss that it was applying to html also. I've added a class of html-styling to the html tag and added it alongside body.body-styling to fix the issue. Is there another approach you would've used?

Answer (score -1):

Try using !important so that all subsequent rules on an element are to be ignored, and the rule denoted by ! important is to be applied. It will override all previous styling rules.